# "Fun Killer' Phrase

Tags: single-word-requests

Can we use the phrase “fun killers” to describe people who watch the new episode of a show and start talking about it in front of their friends, who have not watched it yet, to spoil and ruin the surprising part of the episode?

Does the phrase 'fun-killers' in this context equal the word 'spoilers'? 
In other words, can I use spoilers and fun-killer interchangeably?

Comment: If you mean "a killer of fun", then it should be hyphenated: *fun-killer*. Otherwise, *fun* could readily be interpreted as modifying *killer* (similar construction as *you're a fun guy*), meaning your killers are fun to be with. :-)

Comment: Clearly you ***can*** use that phrase - which is what you asked.  Whether it makes any sense is another question!

Comment: Smsm, your edit doesn't address the reason your question was put on hold - see the large message box directly beneath the question, commencing with the words "**put on hold**". *Did you read the information provided in the link about single word requests?*

Comment: I apologize I don't really understand the issue of my question. Does this "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered"  mean that I should put a simple sentence shows the use of the word? If so, I did. Also, Does this  "see: About single word requests" mean I should change the tag? If so, I also did. I apologize again. I'm confused.

Answer (score 4):

Two words that come to mind for "fun killer" are **killjoy**, for which the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/killjoy) has

> **killjoy**
>   NOUN
>
> A person who deliberately spoils the enjoyment of others.
>   *a few killjoys try to reform the seasonal activities*

and the other is **spoilsport**, the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoilsport) has

> **spoilsport**
>   NOUN
>
> A person who behaves in a way that spoils others' pleasure, especially by not joining in an activity.
>   *Don't be a spoilsport, Sidney.*

Also, giving away a punch line or ending is called a [**spoiler**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoiler)

> **spoiler**
>   NOUN
>
> **1** A person or thing that spoils something.
>   *If you've not seen it, there's nothing I can say that's not a spoiler.*
>
> **1.3** A description of an important plot development in a television show, film, or book which if previously known may reduce surprise or suspense for a first-time viewer or reader.
>   *I will try to keep this review as free of spoilers as possible, but the nature of the film requires some revelation.*

So you could say:

> Don't be such a spoiler. I haven't seen the latest episode yet.